# File created by ansible script module not present after running against remote node

Tags: shell, ansible

I'm setting up some server in AWS, and want to use Ansible to do some shell in remote nodes. I write playbook as follow

```
- hosts: remote-nodes
  tasks:
      - name: Execute script
        script: /home/ubuntu/FastBFT_ethereum/experiment/a.sh
```

remote nodes a.sh as follow

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "test">> test.txt
python writejson.py
```

But when I check the test.text, I find it doesn't work in remote nodes.help me please.

Comment: Which directory do you expect that file to be created in? And, err, *why* are you making the assumption that the created file will be in the specific directory you're looking in? :)

Comment: If you want to control which directory is used, pay attention to the `chdir` argument in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want `test.txt` to be created in the `experiment` directory, this should be changed to something like:

```
- hosts: remote-nodes
  tasks:
  - name: Execute script
    script: /home/ubuntu/FastBFT_ethereum/experiment/a.sh
    args:
      chdir: /home/ubuntu/FastBFT_ethereum/experiment
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem.

Comment: Glad to help! If the problem is indeed solved, please click the checkbox to the left, which will make the question show up as no longer needing answers.